# How to convert BackgroundWork to control in c#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, backgroundworker, new-operator

Hell I'm tryping to convert BackgroundWork to control, but it's say:

> Error 6 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Here is code

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
this.Controls.Add(bw);
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

How to make thing work?

I try cast bw to control but same thing, here is what i try:

```
this.Controls.Add((this.Control)bw);
```

Comment: You can't add a backgroundworker as a Control...What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to send mail in background ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Just remove this line

```
this.Controls.Add(bw);
```

`BackgroundWorker` does not derive from `Control` so you can't add it to the `Controls`collection but you don't need to do this anyway.

Comment: You're very welcome :-) You can mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a `BackgroundWorker` to your Form's Controls.

It is just an object that exists independently.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're adding the worker object to the controls collection...

To send emails you could simply pass in a worker method which is bound to the objects `DoWorkEventHandler`, looks like you're part way there already: -

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
this.Controls.Add(bw); //REMOVE THIS LINE
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

//If your email relies on data from some object you can pass it in as a parameter
bw.RunWorkerAsync([email object])
```

Then you need to have a worker method set up to handle the sending of emails: -

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     Email email = (Email)sender;
     //Send email
}
```

You might also want to know when the current job is complete, in which case you could use something like this inside of the do work method: -

```
this.Invoke(new JobDone(ReportProgress), result);
```

With a delegate defined as:

```
private delegate void JobDone(Result result);
```

And the `ReportProgress` method looking something like:-

```
private void ReportProgress(Result result)
{

}
```